# Google Sheets pull data from one cell if criteria matches another

Tags: google-sheets

So I have a spreadsheet which lists all of our employees, and which team they belong to. In one column is first/last name, in another is the team they're assigned to.

[image: Employees/Teams]

In separate spreadsheet/workbook, I want to organize employees, by team.

[image: Sorted employees based on teams]

I seem to be running into a wall on this one.

Comment: Did you tried a formula, a script or something else?

Answer (score 1):

After messing around with this for a while, I finally found an answer with the filter function, which I didn't know existed. Before, I was attempting to use a vlookup, but wasn't achieving what I wanted.

```
=filter(Sheet1!A:A,Sheet1!B:B="CRITERA TO SORT BY")
```

This got me what I wanted.